# Delphi: ResolveToDataset issue

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I am using a `TClientDataset` with the following options for the provider:

```
ResolveToDataSet = True
Options = [poPropogateChanges, poUseQuoteChar]
UpdateMode = upWhereKeyOnly
AfterUpdateRecord = DataSetProvider1AfterUpdateRecord
```

The provider is connected to a **[TIBCQuery](https://docs.devart.com/ibdac/?devart.ibdac.tibcquery.htm)** which manages the generator for the `NO_INVOICE` key.

On **[AfterUpdateRecord](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Datasnap.Provider.TBaseProvider.AfterUpdateRecord)** the following code is done (as found in many places in groups to really propagate the key change when posting to the database)

```
DeltaDS.FieldByName(ClientDataSet1NO_INVOICE.FieldName).NewValue 
  := SourceDS.FieldByName(ClientDataSet1NO_INVOICE.FieldName).NewValue
```

The following code is then used to add a record:

```
  ClientDataSet1.Params[0].AsInteger := -1;
  ClientDataSet1.Open;
  ClientDataSet1.Edit;
  ClientDataSet1NO_INVOICE.AsInteger := -1;
  ClientDataSet1NO_STORE.AsInteger := 1;
  ClientDataSet1.Post;
  ClientDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(-1);
```

If I call **[ClientDataSet1.Refresh](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Refresh)** after the [ApplyUpdate](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Datasnap.Provider.TCustomProvider.ApplyUpdates), the underlying **TIBCQuery** is reopened with the original param of `-1` and not with the new key—even if the `ClientDataSet1NO_INVOICE.AsInteger` shows up the new value assigned after merging records.

The use of **Refresh** here is only to simplify this example. The problems happens when we:

- insert a record
- apply updates
- and edit the record again

Did I miss something with the usage of the **[ResolveToDataset](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Datasnap.Provider.TDataSetProvider.ResolveToDataSet)** option, or should I explicitly reopen the query with the new param?

I never had this problem before when using `ResolveToDataset = False` on other projects.

Comment: Why `Edit` and not `Insert` or `Append` to add a record? Is your ClientDataSet1.Params[0].ParamType = ptInputOutput?

Comment: The Edit was a copy and paste issue... Same problem with append.  Strangely the IBCQuery (from Devart) doesn't support ptInputOutpout params... it gives: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -804
SQLDA missing or incorrect version, or incorrect number/type of variables'